# how to block didSelectRowAtIndexPath for a subview?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

In my tableview, I used custom cell which contains a checkbox. Code to add the checkbox in custom cell class is:

```
checkbox = [[SSCheckBoxView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 20, 20)
                                                    style:kSSCheckBoxViewStyleGlossy
                                                  checked:NO];
[self addSubview:checkbox];
```

My problem is whenever i click on the checkbox it will call `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. how to block this?

Comment: Yo need to add a custom button on your SSCheckBoxView and add target and selector for that button. after that when u click on that didSelectRow will not get called it will call the selector of button

Comment: Donot override the didSelectRowForIndexPath method

Answer (score 4):

You will have to add a `UIButton` or make the checkbox as a button and then `addsubview` it in the `UITabelViewCell`. This will override the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method itself and the button click would make Your action. Also make the Button a bit bigger in size so that the clickable area is justified. Hope this helps.

**EDIT :**

So if u want to do it i have a way add a bool value `IsChecked = YES` to the checkbox method. Then when the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method is called , in it add

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {

       if(IsChecked == NO)
       { 
         Ischecked = NO; 
         // Add your methods 
       }
    }
```

Hope you got it ....

Comment: i already added a target method [checkbox setStateChangedTarget:self selector:@selector(checkboxViewStateChanged:)];. but after checkboxViewStateChanged called, didSelectRowAtIndexPath also getting called

Answer (score 3):

You can stop selection of by returning nil for the index path. Use the following code.

```
-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return nil;
}
```